# How to use max() with arrayformula()

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

This is my sheet :

[image]

in column E, i want to find the max among col A,B,C using this simple formula in E1 :

```
=max(A1:C1)
```

But rather than pasting the formula to E2 .. E10, i want to see if possible to use `max()` in `arrayformula()` ? so i can use single formula for the whole column E.

Answer (score 2):

#### Formula

```
=BYROW(A:C, LAMBDA(r, 
   IFERROR(MAX(r)/(COUNT(r)>0))))
```

- Uses `COUNT(r)>0` to return `1` if there are any values in the row, or `0` if the row only contains blank cells.
- Dividing by zero always returns an error which IFERROR handles by returning an empty value, which effectively skips blank rows.

Answer (score 1):

If your data to compare is really only in three columns (A, B, C), you can simplify things with this formula in E1:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A:A="",,IF((A:A>B:B)*(A:A>C:C),A:A,IF(B:B>C:C,B:B,C:C))))`

This reads "If any row of A is blank, return null; otherwise, if A is greater than B *and* A is greater than C, return A; otherwise, if B is greater than C, return B; otherwise, return C."

If you will have more columns than three *and* you know you will have fewer than 5500 rows of data *and* your numbers to compare will be similar in length to those shown in your post (i.e., numbers with 3 or fewer digits), then you can use this in E1:

`=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A:C,A:A<>"")),"SELECT "&JOIN(",","MAX(Col"&SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A),1)&")")),2))`

This essentially takes all non-null rows, `TRANSPOSE`s them, forms a `QUERY` that retrieves the `MAX` from as many columns as the original data set has rows, and then `TRANSPOSE`s everything back to the original orientation again.

The limitations are based on the fact that `JOIN` can only concatenated up to 50,000 characters. So if your real numbers may be up to 6 characters long, you can get about 4500 rows out of the above formula, etc.

Answer (score 0):

### The lambda way

The `max()` function is an aggregating function so it will not give row-by-row results in an array formula.

To iterate the data row by row, use `byrow()` with a lambda function that gets the max value on each row separately, like this:

```
=let( 
  data, A1:C, 
  rowMax_, lambda(r, iferror(1 / max(r) ^ -1)), 
  byrow(data, rowMax_) 
)
```

See
[let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535),
[lambda()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718),
[byrow()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) and
[iferror()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093304).

### The old way

Before lambda functions became available in September 2022, row-by-row aggregation of data was often implemented with array formulas using the likes of `mmult()`, `sumif`, `countif()`, `countifs()` and `query()`, or "database" functions such as `daverage()`, `dcount()`, `dcounta()`, `dget()`, `dmax()`, `dmin()`, `dproduct()`, `dstdev()`, `dstdevp()`, `dsum()`, `dvar()` and `dvarp()`.

One pattern to get row-by-row max values is to apply `transpose()` and use `dmax()` with blank criteria created with `iferror()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula(iferror( 
  1 / dmax( 
    transpose({ row(A1:C), A1:C }), 
    row(A1:C), 
    iferror(A1:C / 0) 
  ) ^ -1 
))
```

See
[dmax()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094227),
[transpose()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262),
[row()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316)
and
[iferror()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093304).

Comment: [dmax()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094227) expects a header row, but a virtual header can be inserted as shown in the new formula.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this is with either byrow or bycol formulas.
If you're looking for the max value of multiple rows, then if would look something like this:

> =bycol(A1:C5,lambda(_c,max(_c)))

You can swap the logic to be byrow, and/or insert empty value logic into this as you need.